# Error getting reflective information for class

Tags: java, wildfly, wildfly-10

I am running dynamic web project in Wildfly 10.1.0. I have richfaces-ui.3.3.3.jar in my WEB-INF\lib folder but I am still getting this error.

I have this library included in my web-inf folder

[image]

```
10:32:09,011 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYSRV0028: Stopped deployment RGWeb.war (runtime-name: RGWeb.war) in 110ms
10:32:09,012 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "RGWeb.war" (runtime-name: "RGWeb.war")
10:32:18,918 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYSRV0059: Class Path entry logkit-1.2.jar in /D:/wildfly-10.1.0.Final/standalone/deployments/RGWeb.war/WEB-INF/lib/jacorb.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
10:32:18,919 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYSRV0059: Class Path entry avalon-framework-4.1.5.jar in /D:/wildfly-10.1.0.Final/standalone/deployments/RGWeb.war/WEB-INF/lib/jacorb.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
10:32:18,919 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYSRV0059: Class Path entry concurrent-1.3.2.jar in /D:/wildfly-10.1.0.Final/standalone/deployments/RGWeb.war/WEB-INF/lib/jacorb.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
10:32:18,919 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYSRV0059: Class Path entry antlr-2.7.2.jar in /D:/wildfly-10.1.0.Final/standalone/deployments/RGWeb.war/WEB-INF/lib/jacorb.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
10:32:18,936 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYSRV0059: Class Path entry activation.jar in /D:/wildfly-10.1.0.Final/standalone/deployments/RGWeb.war/WEB-INF/lib/mail.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
10:32:19,679 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-4) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."RGWeb.war".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."RGWeb.war".POST_MODULE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment "RGWeb.war"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:154)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: WFLYSRV0177: Error getting reflective information for class com.revguru.crs.web.rm.vo.RevenueRules with ClassLoader ModuleClassLoader for Module "deployment.RGWeb.war:main" from Service Module Loader
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentReflectionIndex.getClassIndex(DeploymentReflectionIndex.java:70)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.metadata.MethodAnnotationAggregator.runtimeAnnotationInformation(MethodAnnotationAggregator.java:57)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.handleAnnotations(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:106)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.processComponentConfig(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:91)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.deploy(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:76)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:147)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg/richfaces/component/html/HtmlDataTable;
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2583)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1916)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.ClassReflectionIndex.<init>(ClassReflectionIndex.java:72)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentReflectionIndex.getClassIndex(DeploymentReflectionIndex.java:66)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.richfaces.component.html.HtmlDataTable from [Module "deployment.RGWeb.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:198)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:363)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:351)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:93)
    ... 15 more

10:32:19,680 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("full-replace-deployment") failed - address: ([]) - failure description: {
    "WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"RGWeb.war\".POST_MODULE" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"RGWeb.war\".POST_MODULE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment \"RGWeb.war\"
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: WFLYSRV0177: Error getting reflective information for class com.revguru.crs.web.rm.vo.RevenueRules with ClassLoader ModuleClassLoader for Module \"deployment.RGWeb.war:main\" from Service Module Loader
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg/richfaces/component/html/HtmlDataTable;
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.richfaces.component.html.HtmlDataTable from [Module \"deployment.RGWeb.war:main\" from Service Module Loader]"},
    "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.deployment.unit.\"RGWeb.war\".POST_MODULE"],
    "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => undefined
}
10:32:19,710 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) WFLYSRV0016: Replaced deployment "RGWeb.war" with deployment "RGWeb.war"
10:32:19,711 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) WFLYCTL0183: Service status report
WFLYCTL0186:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.unit."RGWeb.war".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."RGWeb.war".POST_MODULE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment "RGWeb.war"
      service jboss.deployment.unit."RGWeb.war".POST_MODULE
```

Comment: Have you checked  if org.richfaces.component.html.HtmlDataTable class is present in the included jar file ?

Answer (score 2):

From Wildfly.org webpage:

> Java 7 support has been discontinued allowing for deeper
>   integration with the Java 8 runtime. While Java 9 is still in
>   development, this release runs on the current development snapshots.

Please make sure, you build your war with Java 1.8

Answer (score 2):

I got this error when I accidently deployed a JAR file instead of a WAR file. Sometimes it's not easy to figure out such simple failures.
Maybe this is your case?
Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

In my case when i try to deploy a war file it gave me the error you are pointing.
the thing is there is a line called
`java.lang.**NoClassDefFoundError**: Lorg/richfaces/component/html/HtmlDataTable; at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)`

that means wildfly is looking for  `Lorg/richfaces/component/html/HtmlDataTable`
and it cannot find that in given location

you can check if the module is really there.if not put the module to correct location and it will work.hope this is helpfull to someone

Answer (score 0):

This error comes if your java class is referring for some jar or xml file like persistence.xml and does not exists

Comment: Could you please add detail to your answer? How could one resolve this?