# WFLYSRV0177: Error getting reflective information for class

Tags: eclipse, maven

I am developing a JEE project using Eclipse JEE (2019-09), Maven, Wildfly 17, JSF, PrimeFaces 7.0 running on Ubuntu 18.04.
My project used to compile, deploy and run on the WildFly 17 server until today. However, because I recieved strange errors when debugging, I installed an earlier Eclipse IDE to try to run my project on it.
After installing the older version of Eclipse (2019-03) in its  own dedicated workspace, I got this error message when deploying my application to WildFly:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: WFLYSRV0177: Error getting reflective information for class
```

I then switched back to my initial Eclipse JEE (2019-09) Version, but then I kept recieving the same error message upon deploying.
I' ve searched the internet and found these two similar problems:

[Error getting reflective information for class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41994628/error-getting-reflective-information-for-class)

[Wildfly: Error getting reflective information for class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46986796/wildfly-error-getting-reflective-information-for-class)

but actually not a solution to my problem.

Could somebody please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that the Maven jar- dependencies were not added to the WEB-INF/lib path.
Actually, in the deployed .war file the folder WEB-INF/lib was completely missing.
I fixed the problem by right-mouse click on my project in Eclipse, then "Properties", then "Deployment Assembly".
I added the missing entry "Maven Dependencies" as follows:

1.) BEFORE MY FIX:

[image]

2.) AFTER MY FIX:

[image]

Comment: Better to switch to a build tool like maven which integrates nicely with eclipse

Comment: @Kukeltje  Thank you for your useful comment! Yes, I have always been using Maven. Before and after the above problem. I mean the  Maven tool, which is integrated into Eclipse.

Comment: Then what  you did should not be needed. I never did this. Sure you have the m2e plugins running etc?

Comment: @Kukeltje yep, you are right! I have never done this  before also. What is more interesting is that it used to work until a couple of days ago. I' ve no idea what might have caused the problem.  I am also not sure whether m2e plugins are running, but  since now I am able do develop, deploy and debug my application as usual, I assume everything works OK. Thank you once again for your valuable opinion!